# reorganize svn repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, branch, reorganize

I created svn repositories, without worrying about branches, etc. Now, I want to create branch.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041/how-do-i-create-a-branch-in-svn) says I can create branch by copying. However, as I do not have trunk/branches folder, whats the right way /commands to reorganize the directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create and check in a folder named trunk, move all your files and folders to the trunk folder with [`svn move`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html). If you have TortoiseSVN you can move with the repository browser.

Then create a folder named `branches` and one named `tags` and you should be back on track with a standard layout.

There is nothing special with trunk, tags and branches, it is just a naming convention.