# Ignore specific commit in svn when showing annotation

Tags: eclipse, svn

I use the "show annotation" functionality quite often. Now, I accidentally crushed the svn and solved it by making a re-commit of everything. Now, every time I use the "show annotation" function, it shows this last commit on every line.

Can I revert this somehow?

Comment: I don't think you can change history...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you didn't kill the entire SVN and "solved" that by starting over from rev 1. I'm assuming some intermediate revision got corrupted and you had to touch and commit every file in a new revision, but older revisions are visible and accessible in the SVN history. The Annotations feature, and Plan B both rely on that.

---

## What the textbook offers

Excluding a single mid-range revision is not possible, given a certain history. You can only exclude head or tail ranges by specifying revisions other than `1` for the "From" and `HEAD` for the "To".

Say the "repair" revision you want to exclude is `r1000`. To exclude it, you can choose to consider either (from-to) `r1-r999` or `r1001-HEAD`, leaving out `r1000`. So you are confined to either viewing the changes before or after the repair.

You can read up on the possibilities and options of what's internally called *svn blame* [in the SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html).

[image: Show Annotation dialog]

## Plan B

Now, that's not really satisfying, I imagine. Here's something else you can try, but please create a backup of your repo first.

1. With the help of the SVN history viewer, or log viewer, find the last revision before the corrupted revision, say `r997`.
2. [Make a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041/how-do-i-create-a-branch-in-svn) based off that last good revision.
3. Then delete or move the current trunk, using the [corresponding SVN commands](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/de/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html).
4. In the last step, move or branch(=copy) the branch back to the trunk location.

You have effectively cut out the corrupt revisions. The branch-now-trunk has a "hole" in its revision numbers, because branching off `r997` created a new revision younger than the corrupted and repairing revisions. Afterwards, showing annotations on that new trunk will work like before, but wont include the corruption and your "repair".

Here, I made an illustration for you:

[image: freehand trunk replace illustration]

This operation *can* screw up some ancestry operations like merging, but I've done it successfully before, even with large merging operations later on, so you might as well try it, too. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!