# create a new folder in SVN tags copy file to SVN from Jenkins workspace

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, ant, copy

I am checking the code from SVN branch from a *change number* folder to Jenkins. Once the build is success, the artifacts(.WAR) are saving in the Jenkins workspace. I need to create a new folder under SVN /tags/DEV with same *change number* and copy .WAR file to same folder. Any suggestions please.

Comment: I think the command line **svn copy** [How do i create a branch in svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041/how-do-i-create-a-branch-in-svn).

Comment: hi@Emile, I want to sheckin code to tags from Jenkins workspace. In order to copy code with in subversion then we can use SVN copy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to be in a SVN working directory. So, what I did is checking out one file from svn. This will turn your directory into a working directory. After that, you can use svn copy command.